# Execute SharedMemory Executable under MPI

Tags: c, linux, mpi, shared-memory

I have a program, say, g09.x that enable Parallel Execution on Shared Memory Processors.

Now I have 8 cores, and I divide it into two groups using mpi.
 For each group, I want them to execute g09.x using 4 cores respectively.

Do anyone have some experience or idea about how to do this?

The MPI_Group is constructing as following, but the region  /* Execute Shared Memory Program */ is still leaving blank!

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rank, group_rank, numtasks, group_size, rc,
      group1[4]={0,1,2,3},
      group2[4]={4,5,6,7};

  MPI_Group orig_group, new_group;
  MPI_Comm  group_comm;

  rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  if (rc !=0){
     printf("MPI_aborted\n");
     MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
  }

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  /* Extract the original group handle */
  MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &orig_group);

 /* Divide tasks into two distinct groups based upon rank */
 if (rank < 4){
     MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, 4, group1, &new_group);
 }
 else {
     MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, 4, group2, &new_group);
 }

 /* Create new communicator */
 MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &group_comm);
 MPI_Group_size(new_group, &group_size);
 MPI_Group_rank(new_group, &group_rank);

 printf("rank=%d, group_rank=%d, numtasks=%d, group_size=%d\n", rank, group_rank,      numtasks, group_size);

  /* Do Something */
  /* Execute Shared Memory Program */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If g09.x is a Parallel Executable instead of shared memory one, does it make this problem easier?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to launch multiple instances of Gaussian09. What prevents you from simply starting two copies with each copy configured to use 4 CPUs?